# How to change mouse speed permanently in Ubuntu 16.04LTS?

Tags: command-line, mouse, gui

I can use the command `xset m 1` in terminal to adjust my mouse speed, 
 but I have to re type it every time I restart my computer.

Is there a way to change it persistently?

Answer (score 0):

You can always change your mouse sensivity by going to **settings** -> **Mouse & Touchpad**.

You will be able to change the sensivity there.
[image]